# How to replace ListItem with custom HTML in select in webforms

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

I'm using WebForms in an application where my code behind generates an HtmlSelect:

```
HtmlSelect teamfilter = new HtmlSelect();
teamfilter.ID = "team_filter_" + studioId;
teamfilter.Attributes.Add("class", "col-md-9");
teamfilter.Attributes.Add("multiple", "true");

ListItem listItem = new ListItem("All " + studioName, "studio_" + studioId);
listItem.Attributes.Add("data-type", "studio");
teamfilter.Items.Add(listItem);
```

On the client side I'm using a plugin which allows ListItems to be grouped with a header in the list using a  tag. In other words the rendered HTML must appear as:

```
<select id="blah">
    <optgroup label="Games">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

I need to generate this Select in the code behind using the HtmlSelect class and the ListItem class but how do I add an item so that it renders the starting and closing optgroup tags?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no way to do that. You would have to write your own custom control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't do it only in code behind.

Keep the code behind generating the `HtmlSelect` this way you're doing, and with jQuery, maybe you can do something like this:

```js
$("select[id='blah'] option").wrap("<optgroup label='Games'></<optgroup>");
```